# (SwiftUI) How to refresh the count down

Tags: swiftui

I want the count down to restart when I enter next quiz. Now the count down just continues. Do you know how to fix this problem? Thank you.  Following is the reproducible code.

### TemplateView.swift

Since the header and the footer is same for all quizes. I am using the template view to avoid redundancy.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TemplateView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TemplateViewModel()
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InfoView(model: model)
            
            
            Text(model.getContent(idx: model.currentIdx))

            
            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right.fill")
                .onTapGesture {
                    if model.currentIdx >= model.data.count-1 {
                        model.currentIdx = 0
                    } else {
                        model.currentIdx += 1
                    }
                   
                }
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

### TemplateViewModel

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


class TemplateViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIdx: Int = 0
    
    var data: [QuizModel] = [
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 10, content: "Answer the short question"),
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 20, content: "Listen to the audio"),
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 30, content: "Read the article"),
    ]
    
    var time: Int {
        return data[currentIdx].prepareSeconds
    }
    
    func getTime(idx: Int) -> Int {
        return data[idx].prepareSeconds
    }
    
    func getContent(idx: Int) -> String {
        return data[idx].content
    }
}
```

### InfoView

```
import SwiftUI

struct InfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TemplateViewModel

    @State var prepareSeconds: Int = 0
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    
    init(model: TemplateViewModel) {
        self.model = model
        self._prepareSeconds = State(initialValue: model.getTime(idx: model.currentIdx))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(prepareSeconds.description)
            .onReceive(timer, perform: { _ in
                if prepareSeconds  > 0 {
                    prepareSeconds -= 1
                }
            })
            
    }
}
```

### QuizModel.swift

This the data model, `prepareSeconds` means how many seconds the participant can prepare for this quiz. `content` is the quiz content.

```
struct QuizModel {
    var prepareSeconds: Int
    var content: String
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just add an `id` to `InfoView` so that it is forced to reset its state when the ID changes:

```
InfoView(model: model).id(model.currentIdx)
```

However, architecturally, I'm not sure that makes the most sense. I'd store the timer in your ObservableObject:

```
struct TemplateView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TemplateViewModel()
    

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            InfoView(model: model)
            
            Text(model.getContent(idx: model.currentIdx))

            
            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right.fill")
                .onTapGesture {
                    if model.currentIdx >= model.data.count-1 {
                        model.currentIdx = 0
                    } else {
                        model.currentIdx += 1
                    }
                    model.countDownFrom(seconds: model.getTime(idx: model.currentIdx))
                }
        }.onAppear {
            model.countDownFrom(seconds: model.getTime(idx: model.currentIdx))
        }
    }
}


class TemplateViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var currentIdx: Int = 0
    
    @Published var prepareSeconds: Int = 0
    private var cancellable : AnyCancellable?
    
    var data: [QuizModel] = [
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 10, content: "Answer the short question"),
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 20, content: "Listen to the audio"),
        QuizModel(prepareSeconds: 30, content: "Read the article"),
    ]
    
    var time: Int {
        return data[currentIdx].prepareSeconds
    }
    
    func getTime(idx: Int) -> Int {
        return data[idx].prepareSeconds
    }
    
    func getContent(idx: Int) -> String {
        return data[idx].content
    }
    
    func countDownFrom(seconds: Int) {
        prepareSeconds = seconds
        cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect().sink(receiveValue: { (_) in
            if self.prepareSeconds  > 0 {
                self.prepareSeconds -= 1
            }
        })
    }
}

struct InfoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: TemplateViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(model.prepareSeconds.description)
    }
}

struct QuizModel {
    var prepareSeconds: Int
    var content: String
}
```

More refactoring that could be done, but that'll get you started.